# Converting unix timestamp (length 13) string to readable date in Python

Tags: python, unix, unix-timestamp

i am tring to convert this unix timestamp 1491613677888 to readable date.
found here (stackoverflow) that python script:

```
import datetime
print(
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
    int("1284101485")
    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)
```

but when i put my timestamp there, i got that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

now i see that the timestamp that i am using is 3 chars longer.
i checked it on this link:
http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

and saw that its get the time out of it.
how can i do it using python?
(i am using python 3.4)

Comment: Can't reproduce (python2.7 + 3)

Comment: Where did you get the final 888 in your timestamp? The first part `1491613677` is 2017-04-08T01:07:57+00:00, which is probably what you wanted. With it, your code works perfectly.

Comment: Did you get it from some function that outputs it in milliseconds?

Comment: When I use `int("1284101485888")` on Python 2 I get *ValueError: year is out of range*, on Python 3.6 I get *42661-07-22 17:11:28*.

Comment: regarding to @ThierryLathuille comment. yes, i need the milliseconds.
how can i use it in python 3.4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `timestamp` is not the 'classical' Unix timestamp (number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970), as it is expressed in milliseconds.

You can translate it like this:

```
import datetime

timestamp_with_ms = 1491613677888

# We separate the 'ordinary' timestamp and the milliseconds
timestamp, ms = divmod(timestamp_with_ms, 1000)
#1491613677 888

# We create the datetime from the timestamp, we must add the 
# milliseconds separately
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp) + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=ms)


formatted_time = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
# With Python 3.6, you could use:
# formatted_time = dt.isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')

print(formatted_time)
# 2017-04-08 03:07:57.888
```

**Edit:** I hadn't noticed that `fromtimestamp` accepts a float. So, we can simply do:

```
import datetime
timestamp_with_ms = 1491613677888

dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_with_ms / 1000)

formatted_time = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
# With Python 3.6, you could use:
# formatted_time = dt.isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')

print(formatted_time)
# 2017-04-08 03:07:57.888
```

Answer (score 2):

Your timestamp is 3 characters longer AND is a standard unix timestamp? That would mean your timestamp is at least 40,000 years into the future from today. Otherwise, the last 3 characters may represent something else, like milliseconds but that doesn't explain the error you're seeing.

If they are the milliseconds, and seeing how you're not using them in the format string, I see no harm in simply stripping them.

```
standard_unix_ts = int("1284101485000"[:-3])
```

**EDIT** Taking into account the comment of @cdarke, I'd suggest this instead:

```
standard_unix_ts = int("1284101485000"[:10])
```

**EDIT 2** Following Gils comment

```
import datetime

not_unix_ts = "1284101485088"
unix_ts, milliseconds = not_unix_ts[:10], not_unix_ts[10:]
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(unix_ts))
FORMAT_STRING = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
print("%s and %s milliseconds" % (dt.strftime(FORMAT_STRING), milliseconds))
```

Comment: Just a thought, it might be safer to take the first 10 characters rather than stripping the last 3, in case there is a timestamp of the correct length.

Comment: Very valid comment, I entirely agree.

Comment: in the link that I added, I saw milliseconds - and i need them. that timestamp is part of a key. I need all of it. so how can i get the milliseconds too in python 3.4?

Comment: simply strip them from the string, giving you a real time stamp and the last 3 characters represent your milliseconds. to re-iterate: unix timestamps do *not* include milliseconds so it's understandable that libraries have problems parsing them. I've my answer to better demonstrate this.